# Confusing deinit behavior in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, networking, memory-management, nsurlsession

In my code I have an `APIManager` and a subclass from it `ArticleAPIManager` in both classes I have implemented `deinit { print("deinit className") }`

I was trying to see if the following code will be deallocated immediately:

```
ArticleManager().fetchArticlesWithParameters(ArticlesParameters.defaultParameters()) { (articlesData, error) -> Void in

        print("Done")
    }
```

the console shows the following :

`deinit ArticleAPIManager`

`deinit APIManager`

`Done`

if the Manager is deallocated before, how the completion handler still exist ?

```
func fetchArticleWithParameters<R:xxxProtocol>(parameters:R , completionHandler: ArticleCompletionHandler) {

        if let articleURLWithParamsURL = params.endPointURL() {

        fetchURL(articleURLWithParameters) { (jsonData, error) -> Void in

            guard let jsonData = jsonData else {
                completionHandler(articlesData: nil, error: error)
                return
            }

            if let rawArray = jsonData["data"] as? [APIJSON] {
                let articles = APIGenericResponceParser<T>().parseArray(rawArray)

                completionHandler(articlesData: articles, error:nil)

            }

            }//fetchURL
        }//iflet-NSURL

}
```

Comment: How does your `fetchArticlesWithParameters` look like?

Comment: here lack your api implementation. But typically your closure callback is captured by a async api for calling later.(eg: dispatch after). So your class deinit first. and when async API fire, callback execute

Comment: @AntonBronnikov I have updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to explain through a simple example:

```
class Test {

    let someProperty = "Very nice property"

    func printWithDelay() {

        //Prints done after 3 seconds
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC * 3)), dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            print("Done")
        }
    }

    deinit {
        print("\(self) is deinited")
    }
}
```

And using this code with it:

```
var test: Test? = Test()
test?.printWithDelay()
test = nil
```

In this example, `dispatch_after`'s **block doesn't refer to any of** `Test`'s **properties**, **so it doesn't retain it**, that's why you will see

```
Test is deinited
Done
```

in the console, just like in your example. However, if you print `someProperty` in `printWithDelay`, like:

```
func printWithDelay() {

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC * 3)), dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        print(self.someProperty)
    }
}
```

then you will see

```
Very nice property
Test is deinited
```

in the console, since the block of `dispatch_after` retain `self` and doesn't let it deinited before the block is executed.

Comment: as u said the `dispatch_after ` retain `self`. so if `self` is retained why the deinit is being called ? shouldn't be `self.retainCount == 0` in order to call deinit ?

Comment: @Bobj-C in the first example, `self` is not retained, that's why it is deallocated. In the second version of `printWithDelay` that I wrote, there `self ` is retained.

Answer (score 0):

Closures are reference types in Swift.  You can pass them from place to place just like any other "usual" object.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID104):

> Whenever you assign a function or a closure to a constant or a variable, you are actually setting that constant or variable to be a *reference* to the function or closure... This also means that if you assign a closure to two different constants or variables, both of those constants or variables will refer to the same closure:

In your case you take `completionHandler` and pass it to `fetchURL` (through `endPointURL`), so it's then captured by `fetchURL` and kept alive even though the object of `ArticleAPIManager` that passed it is already dead.  Once fetching is done, the completion handler is executed.  In your case it happens already after the object of `ArticleAPIManager` is deinitialized.